# Ergodicity and spin connections at the event horizon

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, ergodicity

Hawking famously relates the entropy $S$ to the surface area of a black hole $A$ as $S=A/4$. Should I be thinking of the entropy as the number of possible configurations of a spin connection at the event horizon? Is there some ergodic process that is supposed to be stirring the spin connection, so that it becomes a uniform micro-canonical ensemble there? Is that stirring due to a random thermal bath of gravitational waves impinging on the event horizon?